# How to find a control (textbox) that was created during rowCommand and get its value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have added a GridView to my webform. I then bounded data to the gridview programatically, followed by adding a RowDataBound function so that I can have each cell, in the gridView selectable as such:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton _singleClickButton = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
            string clickInfo = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(_singleClickButton, "");
            // Add events to each editable cell
            for (int columnIndex = 3; columnIndex < e.Row.Cells.Count; columnIndex++)
            {
                // Add the column index as the event argument parameter
                string jsClick = clickInfo.Insert(clickInfo.Length - 2, columnIndex.ToString());
                // Add this javascript to the onclick Attribute of the cell
                e.Row.Cells[columnIndex].Attributes["onclick"] = jsClick;
                // Add a cursor style to the cells
                e.Row.Cells[columnIndex].Attributes["style"] += "cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;";
            }
        }
    }
```

...So then what i wanted to do is that whenever a cell is selected, turn that cell red and add a textbox so i can enter a value.. Shown below

```
<Columns>
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="CellClick" Visible="false" ControlStyle-   CssClass="redCell"></asp:ButtonField>
</Columns>
```

codebehind:

```
  public void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.ToString() == "CellClick")
        {
            //INDEX INFO
            int selectedRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            int selectedColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"].ToString());
            //TRIGGERS EVENT FOR SELECTED CELL
                    GridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[selectedColumnIndex].Attributes["style"] += "background-color:Red;";
                    TextBox scheduleBox = new TextBox();
                    scheduleBox.CssClass = "redCell";
                    scheduleBox.ID = "ActiveCell";
                    scheduleBox.Width = 35;
                    this.GridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[selectedColumnIndex].Controls.Add(scheduleBox);
                    scheduleBox.Focus();
            //LABEL INDEX INFO
            lblCell.Text = (selectedColumnIndex - 2).ToString();
            //LABEL HEADER & ROW TITLES
            lblStartTime.Text = GridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[1].Text;

        } 
    }  GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

what I want to do now is once I press enter, get the value that currently resides in the texbox that was created programmatically and for now just display that value on a messagebox or whateevr (what Im really going to do is update a database but first I just need to find out how to get that value)

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1">
<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="ActiveCell" runat="server" Style="display: none"     OnClick="Button1_Click1" /></asp:Panel>
```

and the function Im using is this:

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var schedule = FindControl("ActiveCell") as TextBox;
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page),
             "alert", "alert('VALUE GOES HERE FROM TEXTBOX');", true);
    }
```

So now my question: How can i get the value from ScheduleBox?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to use:

```
<%=schedule.ClientID %>.value
```

I am admittedly not a javascript expert, so let me know if that helps.
also, is the

```
var schedule = FindControl("ActiveCell") as TextBox;
```

returning the textbox correctly?

EDIT: if that doesn't work, try

```
<%=ActiveCell.ClientID %>.value
```

Comment: negative, var schedule = FindControl("ActiveCell") as TextBox; is not returning anything. :( but i'll try the first answer that you suggested.

Comment: @user3850008 Sounds like you need to grab the selected row and then do something like var schedule = GridView1.Rows(selectedRow).FindControl("ActiveCell") as TextBox

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into the controls of the cell of the selected row?
To work around the lack of a selectedColumnIndex in the GridView, I had to change your "GridView1_RowCommand" event to replace one line (to set the ID) and add one more:

```
            scheduleBox.ID = "ActiveCell_" + selectedRowIndex.ToString() + "_" + selectedColumnIndex.ToString();
            scheduleBox.TextChanged += scheduleBox_TextChanged;
```

It would look something like this:

```
int selectedColumnIndex = 0;
int selectedRowIndex = 0;
string lastUserInputText = string.Empty;

    public void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.ToString() == "CellClick")
        {
            //INDEX INFO
            selectedRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            selectedColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"].ToString());
            //TRIGGERS EVENT FOR SELECTED CELL
            GridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[selectedColumnIndex].Attributes["style"] += "background-color:Red;";
            TextBox scheduleBox = new TextBox();
            scheduleBox.CssClass = "redCell";

            //This formats the ID so its unique, and now the TextBox contains the row and colummn indexes:
            scheduleBox.ID = "ActiveCell_" + selectedRowIndex.ToString() + "_" + selectedColumnIndex.ToString();
            scheduleBox.TextChanged += scheduleBox_TextChanged;

            scheduleBox.Width = 35;

            this.GridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[selectedColumnIndex].Controls.Add(scheduleBox);
            scheduleBox.Focus();
            //LABEL INDEX INFO
            lblCell.Text = (selectedColumnIndex - 2).ToString();
            ////LABEL HEADER & ROW TITLES
            lblStartTime.Text = GridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[1].Text;

        }
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

//The following event gets the current index of the Row and the column where the user is changing the text
    void scheduleBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtSelected = (TextBox)sender;
        string[] selectedValues = txtSelected.ID.Split(new char[] { '_' });
        selectedRowIndex = int.Parse(selectedValues[1]);
        selectedColumnIndex = int.Parse(selectedValues[2]);
        //you could also use it to get the text directly while the user is editing it:
        lastUserInputText = txtSelected.Text;
    }

//This gets the text for the selected row and column. But if you only have 1 column with a TextBox it would be easier to just use the column index constant instead of doing it dynamically. However, remember you already have this value in the "lastUserInputText" variable. If you use that the following code may not be necessary:
string GetTextFromSelectedRowTextBox()
{
    string textBoxValue = string.Empty;
    foreach (Control curControl in this.GridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[selectedColumnIndex].Controls)
    {
        if (curControl is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox txtScheduleBox = (TextBox)curControl;
            textBoxValue = txtScheduleBox.Text;
            break;
        }
    }
    return textBoxValue;
}
```

Comment: When I paste that snippet, in my codebehind, I get an error: "The name 'selectedColumnIndex' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: there you go, I changed the code to get the columnIndex, it is a workaround as the GridView control does not facilitate the selectedColumnIndex.